# Отображать комментарий сразу после преобразования ответа

Tags: дефект, инструменты-модератора

При преобразовании ответа в комментарий комментарии отображаются на странице только после её обновления.

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Подобные запросы надо писать на MSE. Это, конечно, тоже часто бесперспективно, но всё же не так как здесь.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ запросы/баг репорты по инструментам модерации там не в приоритете)

Comment: @Suvitruf а тут?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а тут в принципе толку нет. Т.к. разработчики SE нашу мету не читают. Только Адам иногда. Из участников, по-моему, только я и вы что-то на MSE постим, как правило. Так что, такие реквесты лучше сразу на MSE писать ;D